# three.js GLTFLoader() "Unexpected token" error

Tags: javascript, html, json, three.js

I want to load a .glb model into three.js using the GLTFLoader. I succeeded in creating a rotating 3D mesh on a canvas--without errors in the console. However, attempting to replace that with the .glb model returns the following:

```
    VM229545 index.975ef6c8.js:29577 
            
           SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
        at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
        at GLTFLoader.parse (VM229545 index.975ef6c8.js:29637:27)
        at Object.onLoad (VM229545 index.975ef6c8.js:29588:23)
        at VM229545 index.975ef6c8.js:24157:47
```

The VM229646 address leads to the following:

[Syntax Error location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqR4J.png)

Here is my index.js file:

```js
    import '../CSS/main.css'
    import * as THREE from 'three'
    import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js'

    const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader()

    gltfLoader.load('./assets/qmark.glb', (gltf) => {
        scene.add(gltf.scene)
    })

    // Canvas
    const canvas = document.querySelector('#upperq')

    // Scene
    const scene = new THREE.Scene()

    // Lights

    const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.1)
    pointLight.position.x = 2
    pointLight.position.y = 3
    pointLight.position.z = 4
    scene.add(pointLight)

    /**
     * Sizes
     */
    const sizes = {
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', () =>
    {
        // Update sizes
        sizes.width = window.innerWidth
        sizes.height = window.innerHeight

        // Update camera
        camera.aspect = sizes.width / sizes.height
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix()

        // Update renderer
        renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height)
        renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))
    })

    /**
     * Camera
     */
    // Base camera
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, sizes.width / sizes.height, 0.1, 100)
    camera.position.x = 0
    camera.position.y = 0
    camera.position.z = 2
    scene.add(camera)

    // Controls
    // const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, canvas)
    // controls.enableDamping = true

    /**
     * Renderer
     */
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        canvas: canvas,
        alpha: true
    })
    renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height)
    renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))

    /**
     * Animate
     */

    const clock = new THREE.Clock()

    const tick = () =>
    {

        const elapsedTime = clock.getElapsedTime()

        // Update objects
        // sphere.rotation.y = .5 * elapsedTime

        // Render
        renderer.render(scene, camera)

        // Call tick again on the next frame
        window.requestAnimationFrame(tick)
    }

    tick()
```

I sense that my index.html file is attempting to be read, but I'm not sure. How can I resolve this?

I am using Parcel if that's relevant, and I have the parcel-plugin-asset-copier installed.

Comment: Are you sure that url for the glb file is correct? Is it missing a dot at the beginning of the url? Looks somewhat more like a 404 server response is being fed into the parser.

Comment: Resolved by tweaking my directory and, most importantly, serving my .glb correctly. | 1. Install this parcel plug-in: https://github.com/elwin013/parcel-reporter-static-files-copy | 2. Add a ".parcelrc" file and "Static" folder to your project. Configure them as outlined in the directions. | 3. Place .glb file in the "Static" folder. | 4. Build.

Answer (score 0):

The qmark.glb need to be placed in the public folder and then you can load your glf:

```
gltfLoader.load('/qmark.glb', (gltf) => {
  scene.add(gltf.scene)
})
```